# How to get the actual size of a protocol buffer message before serialization?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I defined a message in *.proto file and set the values using reflection.
I need to find out how many bytes are parsed per second with `SerializeToString()` API.
Is it possible to get the actual size of the message before calling SerializeToString?

Comment: why do you need to know the size before? To measure the time it takes you need to call the function and once you did you know the size

Comment: because the number of bytes of the message should be calculated from the original message structure.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. `SerializeToString()` is using the message structure

Comment: The message size depends on how many entries in the message have default values as those aren't included in the serialized message. So there is no cheap way to get the message size.

Comment: As I know all the entries in the message are included in the serialized message.
if not how can we have the values of those fields (in case of changing their value) when doing deserialization?

Comment: My boss asked me how long it would take to make the feature, and the estimate had to be 100% accurate.  I told my boss I'd get right on it, but it'd take a while to get him the estimate. After 3 months and 9 days, I told my boss that it would take 3 months and 9 days to make the feature.  My boss then approved my feature project.  I completed the feature project in 1 day.  I was a rock star hero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which size you're interested in.

If you want to know how large the serialized protobuf message returned by [`MessageLite::SerializeToString()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.SerializeToString.details) is going to be you can use [`Message::ByteSizeLong()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.ByteSizeLong.details).

Example:

```cpp
ExampleMessage msg;
msg.set_example(12);

std::size_t expectedSize = msg.ByteSizeLong();

std::string result;
msg.SerializeToString(&result);

assert(expectedSize == result.size());
```

This is also the way `SerializeToString()` [calculates the size of the message internally](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/520c601c99012101c816b6ccc89e8d6fc28fdbb8/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc#L445-L459) to resize the `std::string` to have enough space for the entire message.

---

On the other hand if you want to know how much memory the message currently requires in unserialized form you can use [`Message::SpaceUsedLong()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.SpaceUsedLong.details) - which will give you an estimate of that size.

Example:

```cpp
ExampleMessage msg;
msg.set_example(12);

std::size_t approximateInMemorySize = msg.SpaceUsedLong();
```

Comment: that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

I have to add more infos because this is not enough and can cause problem.

Your message **does not have a fixed size** and will resize to it's data. for example my simple:

```
message AbstractHeader {
    int32       id = 1;
    MessageType type = 2;
    int32       lenght = 3;
}
```

Setted like that :

```
std::cout << "-> " << wp.ByteSizeLong() << std::endl;
wp.set_id(2147483647);
wp.set_lenght(2147483647);
wp.set_type(Proto::MessageType::ESP32);
std::cout << " byte-> " << wp.ByteSizeLong() << std::endl;
std::string tmpser = "";
wp.SerializeToString(&tmpser);
std::cout << "serialized -> " << tmpser.size() << std::endl;

-> 0
 byte-> 14
serialized -> 14
```

but if you set :

```
wp.set_id(12);
wp.set_lenght(12);

-> 0
 byte-> 6
serialized -> 6
```

**So you cannot use it as a reference end to end size**, i strongly advice simple old header class with a fixed size. not perfect, but get the job done.